# Cannot load html image using localhost node.js/express.js server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm using the following node.js/express.js server,

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port: 8000!');
});
```

and the following html file,

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Will Alley</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <h2 id="myName">Will Alley</h2>
    <img src="./DSC_1546_700_464.jpg" alt="an image.">
</body>
</html>
```

all my files (index.js, index.html, DSC_1546_700_464.jpg) are in the same directory.

when I start my server and navigate to "localhost:8000" all that is displayed is the heading, and the images alt text.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only one route in express, the one for '/'.
Below are two additions, one that answers your specific question by adding `app.use(express.static(__dirname))` which is dangerous.  The safer way is to use something like `app.use('/images',express.static(__dirname+'/images'))` to serve just certain subdirectories where you put servable stuff.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
// Static route for files in the current directory...
// Note that this serves all files relative to the given
// path, even ones you probably don't want.
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Note: you should really put these files in a subdirectory
// And use static like this:
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname +'/images'));    

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port: 8000!');
});
```

Comment: I've added an images subdirectory and used static the way you recommended, but the problem persists. (i also updated the filepath in my html)

Comment: Disregard, I had a type in the modifications, your answer worked, thank you!